# How to allow only the Django authenticated users to view Wordpress contents?

Tags: django, wordpress, authentication, single-sign-on

I have a Django application (SaaS) and a Wordpress blog (documentation/user guide for the SaaS application).

Now I want to make sure that only logged-in user in the SaaS application (Django) should have access or can view the (documentation/user guide) in Wordpress blog.

In the Wordpress, I've added this block in `functions.php` that restricts access to content only to Wordpress members.

```php
function members_only() {
    global $pagenow;
    // Check to see if user in not logged in and not on the login page
    if( !is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php' )
          auth_redirect();
}
add_action( 'wp', 'members_only' );
```

This gives one level of content protection if someone hits direct URL to Wordpress blog.

I do not want to touch the Wordpress code base anymore.

Can I add some authentication mechanism in Django side so that when user clicks on `User Guide` button, they are redirected to the Wordpress site and can view the content.

And if someone has direct hit to Wordpress site they are redirected to the WP login page.

Comment: Does you django app knows username\password of corresponding user from wordpress?

Comment: Actually, scratch that - don't think it's possible for django to provide auth cookies for another site. They have to go through wordpress authorization anyway.